# Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[wait for leader]'

Tags: chef-infra, mesos, mesosphere

I am using the chef cookbook for DCOS on-premise setup. Here are the 2 issues I faced, the second one being the one that I am still stuck on....

**1. Package dcos-el-repo was not found:**

> *10.40.1.2     * Package dcos-el-repo not found: http://repos.mesosphere.io/dcos/el/7/noarch/RPMS/dcos-el-repo-7-0.el7.centos.noarch.rpm*

Note: I was able to bypass this by manually installing the RPM on each node and just commenting out the _repo.rb recipe from running. Not sure why it wouldn't work via recipe though.

**2. execute[wait for leader] action run**

> 10.40.1.9 Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[wait for leader]'
>   10.40.1.9 ================================================================================
>   10.40.1.9 
>   10.40.1.9 
>   10.40.1.9 Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
>   10.40.1.9 ------------------------------------
>   10.40.1.9 Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
>   10.40.1.9 ---- Begin output of ping -c 1 leader.mesos ----
>   10.40.1.9 STDOUT: 
>   10.40.1.9 STDERR: ping: unknown host leader.mesos
>   10.40.1.9 ---- End output of ping -c 1 leader.mesos ----
>   10.40.1.9 Ran ping -c 1 leader.mesos returned 2

Comment: Actually the address of DCOS repo is not a public information

Comment: I can hit that repos URL from a web browser  or even run wget and download the RPM with no issues. But for some reason, the chef run isn't able to do so.